# Jenkins Scripted Pipeline: Groovy if statement

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I can't seem to get the variable `glooNamespaceExists` to actually print.I see in the console the response from `kubectl` is there but the variable seems to be `null` - I'm looking to skip this entire build stage if the namespace already exists..

```
    stage('Setup Gloo Ingress Controller') {
      def glooNamespaceExists = sh(script: "kubectl get ns gloo-system -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}'")

      if (glooNamespaceExists != 'Active') {
        sh 'helm repo add gloo https://storage.googleapis.com/solo-public-helm'
        sh 'helm repo update'
        sh 'kubectl create namespace gloo-system'
        sh 'helm install gloo gloo/gloo --namespace gloo-system'
      }
    }
```

EDIT: Console output of run:

```
[Pipeline] { (Setup Gloo Ingress Controller)
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl get ns gloo-system -o jsonpath={.status.phase}
Active
[Pipeline] sh
+ helm repo add gloo https://storage.googleapis.com/solo-public-helm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `returnStdout: true` to your script command which will return exact output. Otherwise it will return status code which `0`. Please add `returnStdout: true` like this so your command should be like this,

```
def glooNamespaceExists = sh(script: "kubectl get ns gloo-system -o jsonpath='{.status.phase}'", returnStdout: true)
```